# Asymptotic behavior of an integral of a periodic function

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics

Consider $g(x)=e^{\beta \cos(x)}$, and define $Z_N(\beta) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} dx \; g(x) \times \cdots \times g(2^{N-1}x)$. For $N$ large, $Z_N \sim e^{N f(\beta)}$.

The problem is to find $f(\beta) = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{N} \ln Z_N(\beta)$ "exactly".

Observation 1. One can try to find $f(\beta)$ as a Taylor expansion: $f(\beta) = 1 + f_2 \beta^2 + \cdots + f_n \beta^n + \cdots$. However, I cannot see a pattern of how to obtain the general term $f_n$. Is there a pattern?

Observation 2. If I truncate $g(x)$, i.e. $g(x)$ has now a finite number $m$ of Fourier terms, then $f(\beta)$ can be obtained from the largest eigenvalue of some finite matrix. I cannot however see how I can generalize this to larger and larger $m$. Is this possible?

Observation 3. If instead of $\cos(x)$ I use a similarly looking Haar function ${\rm sign} \cos x$, then I can easily calculate $Z_N$ and $f(\beta)$. $Z_N$ is then a partition function of the nearest-neighbor 1 dimensional Ising model. But from the perspective of the observation 2, $g(x)$ has now a non-trivial, infinite Fourier expansion. What does the existence of an exact result mean in this case? How can I recast this result from "knowing" the Fourier coefficients of $g(x)$?

And, perhaps, a more general question. Are integrals of the $Z_N$ type described? To find $f(\beta)$, can one somehow use that fact that $g(x)$ is analytic?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could it be helpful to write $Z_N(\beta)=\int \exp(\sum X_i)$ where $X_i=\beta\cos x$ and think of the $X_i$ as random variables? The covariance of $X_i$ and $X_j$, as well as other measures of dependence, drop precipitously as $|i-j|$ grows. There may be some concentration inequality that works with a sum of random variables, each of which is nealry-independent of all but a few others. If this works, it may be that the main contribution (at least for large $\beta$) comes from the initial segment of length $2^{-N}$ where each $X_i$ is approximately 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "exactly"? If you want a closed form, it may not exist. Do you want to compute to some precision? In that case, I would go with Observation 2 for getting an arbitrarily precise lower bound. Then you get a nearly-matching upper bound by bounding $g$ from above by a truncated Fourier series plus a small constant (which is bigger than the sum of all remaining Fourier coefficients). Then this new upper bound function $\tilde g$ generates its own matrix. As you take more coefficients, the largest eigenvalues of these two matrices should get closer.